# Exception when using ActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

In my application, I use ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS. I have a fragment, called TripFragment, which holds one of the tab. Sometimes I also use DialogFragments to notify user about something, and I don't want this fragments to disappear on screen rotation. So I use the following code:

TripFrament.java:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

With this code I always get the exception when I use ActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem.
Here is the stack trace.

> 01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can not perform this action after
>   onSaveInstanceState 01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.checkStateLoss(FragmentManager.java:1267)
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.enqueueAction(FragmentManager.java:1278)
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.commitInternal(BackStackRecord.java:541)
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   android.app.BackStackRecord.commit(BackStackRecord.java:525) 01-15
>   13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):     at
>   com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.selectTab(ActionBarImpl.java:523)
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   com.android.internal.app.ActionBarImpl.setSelectedNavigationItem(ActionBarImpl.java:306)
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   com.componentix.eurotaxi.TripFragment.goToSelectedPage(TripFragment.java:510)
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   com.componentix.eurotaxi.TripFragment_.access$6(TripFragment_.java:1)
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   com.componentix.eurotaxi.TripFragment_$23.run(TripFragment_.java:457)
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608) 01-15
>   13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):     at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 01-15
>   13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156) 01-15 13:42:20.085:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4987) 01-15
>   13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 01-15
>   13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 01-15 13:42:20.085:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   01-15 13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 01-15
>   13:42:20.085: E/AndroidRuntime(2158):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

I tried to comment call to super() in MainActivity. It hepled with exception, but my DialogFragments started to disappear on screen rotation. So what should I do?

Comment: When and how do you use `ActionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem`?

Comment: Are you sure you don't use old ActionBar instance from already stale activity?